# Convert a 24bit bitmap to grayscale

Tags: performance, c, image, converting, cuda

I wrote this so I can learn CUDA.  This is coded to work on my laptop's Nvidia GeForce GT 540M.

Main points I need reviewed:

1. CUDA programming conventions
2. Performance, especially kernel speed
3. C programming conventions
4. Preprocessor and macro conventions
5. Making it DRY

#### kernel.cu

```
/*************************************************
 *  Part of cuda bitmap to grayscale converter   *
 *  - Bhathiya Perera                            *
 *************************************************/

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "utils.cuh"
#include "bitmap.cuh"
#define PIXEL_SIZE 3

cudaError_t turnGrayWithCuda(unsigned char* bitmapData, BitmapInfoHeader* header, unsigned int size);

// Turn given bitmap data to gray scale
__global__ void turnGray(unsigned char* bitmapData, unsigned long size, unsigned int width)
{
#define xIndex (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x)
#define yIndex (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y)
    unsigned long dataIndex = (xIndex + (yIndex * width)) * PIXEL_SIZE;
#define BLUE bitmapData[dataIndex]
#define GREEN bitmapData[dataIndex+1]
#define RED bitmapData[dataIndex+2]
    // Gray occurs when RED == GREEN == BLUE, so get average
    if(dataIndex < size) {
        unsigned char gray = (RED + GREEN + BLUE) / 3;
        // Convert all pixels to gray
        RED = gray;
        GREEN = gray;
        BLUE = gray;
    }
#undef BLUE
#undef GREEN
#undef RED
#undef xIndex
#undef yIndex
}

void printHelp(char* binary)
{
    printf("GrayScaleCuda\n");
    printf("----------------------------------");
    printf("\t-Bhathiya Perera\n");
    printf("Execute: %s <Bitmap>\n", binary);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
// Freeing data and calling cudaDeviceReset must be done
// All the time
#undef DO_FAILED_EXIT
#define DO_FAILED_EXIT()\
    free(header);\
    free(data);\
    cudaDeviceReset();\
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printHelp(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
#define bitmapFilename "C:\\Users\\Bhathiya\\Desktop\\img.bmp"
#else
#define bitmapFilename argv[1]
#endif

    puts("--------------------------------------------------");
    LOG("Welcome to grayscale with cuda.");

    LOG("Turning %s to grayscale...", bitmapFilename);

    BitmapInfoHeader* header = 0;
    header = (BitmapInfoHeader*)malloc(sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader));
    unsigned char* data = loadBitmapFile(bitmapFilename, header);
    if (data==NULL) {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed to load bitmap");
        DO_FAILED_EXIT();
    }

    cudaError_t cudaStatus = turnGrayWithCuda(data, header, header->sizeImage);
    REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, "Unable to turn grayscale with cuda");

    int success = overwriteBitmapData(bitmapFilename, data);
    if(!success) {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed to overwrite bitmap");
        DO_FAILED_EXIT();
    }

    free(header);
    free(data);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to convert bitmap data to gray
cudaError_t turnGrayWithCuda(unsigned char* bitmapData, BitmapInfoHeader* header, unsigned int size)
{
#undef DO_FAILED_EXIT
#define DO_FAILED_EXIT() cudaFree(devBitmap); return cudaStatus;
    unsigned char* devBitmap = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    size_t dataSize = size * sizeof(unsigned char);
    unsigned long pixelCount = size / PIXEL_SIZE;
    LOG("size=%d, dataSize=%d, pixelCount=%d", size, dataSize, pixelCount);
    LOG("Image Width=%d Height=%d", header->width, header->height);
    cudaStatus = selectBestDevice();
    REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, "Unable to select a cuda device! "
        "Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");

    // Allocate GPU buffer for bitmap data
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&devBitmap, dataSize);
    REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, "Unable allocate device memory");

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(devBitmap, bitmapData, dataSize,
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, "Copying memory failed!");

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(32, 32);
    dim3 blocksPerGrid((header->width + threadsPerBlock.x - 1) / threadsPerBlock.x,
        (header->height + threadsPerBlock.y - 1) / threadsPerBlock.y);

    LOG("CUDA kernel launch with %dx%d blocks of %dx%d threads. Total threads=%d",
        blocksPerGrid.x, blocksPerGrid.y, threadsPerBlock.x, threadsPerBlock.y,
        blocksPerGrid.x * blocksPerGrid.y * threadsPerBlock.x * threadsPerBlock.y);

    CUDA_START_TIMER;
    // Launch a kernel on the GPU
    turnGray<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(devBitmap, size, header->width);
    CUDA_STOP_TIMER;

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, "Kernel launch failed: %s",
        cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));

    // Function cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // Any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, "cudaDeviceSynchronize() returned error"
        " code %d after launching kernel!", cudaStatus);

    CUDA_LOG_TIME(size*2.0f/milliseconds/1e6f);

    // Copy bitmap data from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(bitmapData, devBitmap, dataSize,
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, "Copying memory failed!");

    cudaFree(devBitmap);
    return cudaStatus;
}
```

### Additional Content

You can review these too if you want. But I'm only concerned about **kernel.cu**.

#### utils.cuh

```
#ifndef UTILS_CUH
#define UTILS_CUH

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG_ERROR(message, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] " message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__);
#define LOG(message, ...) printf("[INFO] " message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__);

// Note: `do {} while (0)` is a best practice
// That prevents generating broken code

// Print an array
#define PRINT_ARRAY(data, size)\
    do {\
        LOG("Printing %s...", #data);\
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {\
            LOG("%s[%02d]=%d", #data, i, data[i]);\
        }\
    } while (0)

#define DO_FAILED_EXIT()

// Make sure that a custom DO_FAILED_EXIT is defined
#define REPORT_CUDA_ERROR(cudaStatus, message, ...)\
    do {\
        if(cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {\
            fprintf(stderr, "[CUDA-ERROR] " message "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__);\
            DO_FAILED_EXIT();\
        }\
    } while (0)

#ifndef EXIT_SUCCESS
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#endif

#ifndef EXIT_FAILURE
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1
#endif EXIT_FAILURE

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1
#endif

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif

// Note: these two cannot be put into a `do {} while(0)`
// Since `start` and `stop` should be accessible
#define CUDA_START_TIMER\
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;\
    cudaEventCreate(&start);\
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);\
    cudaEventRecord(start);

#define CUDA_STOP_TIMER cudaEventRecord(stop);

#define CUDA_LOG_TIME(bandwidth)\
    do {\
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);\
        float milliseconds = 0;\
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);\
        LOG("Time taken: %f ms", milliseconds);\
        LOG("Effective Bandwidth: %f GB/s", bandwidth);\
    } while (0)


// Select best GPU for processing
cudaError_t selectBestDevice(void);

#endif // UTILS_CUH
```

#### utils.cu

```
#include "utils.cuh"

// Choose which Best Device to run on
// Based on number of multiProcessors available
cudaError_t selectBestDevice(void)
{
    int selectedDevice = 0;
    int numDevices;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&numDevices);

    if(numDevices > 1) {
        int maxMultiProc = 0;
        int device;
        for(device=0; device < numDevices; ++device) {
            cudaDeviceProp prop;
            cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, device);
            if (maxMultiProc < prop.multiProcessorCount) {
                maxMultiProc = prop.multiProcessorCount;
                selectedDevice = device;
            }
        }
    }

    return cudaSetDevice(selectedDevice);
}
```

#### bitmap.cuh

```
#ifndef BITMAP_CUH
#define BITMAP_CUH

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

// Structure packing
#pragma pack(push, 1)

// Define custom types if not defined before
#ifndef WORD
#define WORD short
#endif

#ifndef DWORD
#define DWORD int
#endif

#ifndef LONG
#define LONG unsigned
#endif

// Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure
// Bitmap structures
typedef struct
{
    WORD type;
    DWORD size;
    WORD reserved1;
    WORD reserved2;
    DWORD offBits;
} BitmapFileHeader;

typedef struct
{
    DWORD size;
    LONG width;
    LONG height;
    WORD planes;
    WORD bitCount;
    DWORD compression;
    DWORD sizeImage;
    LONG xPelsPerMeter;
    LONG yPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD clrUsed;
    DWORD clrImportant;
} BitmapInfoHeader;

#pragma pack(pop)

unsigned char* loadBitmapFile(char* filename, BitmapInfoHeader* bitmapInfoHeader);
int overwriteBitmapData(char* filename, unsigned char* data);

#endif // BITMAP_CUH
```

#### bitmap.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bitmap.cuh"
#include "utils.cuh"

// Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279242/read-bitmap-file-into-structure
// Load bitmap file, create a header object and pass it into access information
unsigned char *loadBitmapFile(char* filename, BitmapInfoHeader* bitmapInfoHeader)
{
    FILE* filePtr;
    BitmapFileHeader bitmapFileHeader;
    unsigned char* bitmapImage = 0;
    int imageIdx = 0;

    // Open filename in read binary mode
    filePtr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (filePtr == NULL) {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed to open file: '%s'", filename);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Read the bitmap file header
    fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), 1, filePtr);

    // Verify that this is a bmp file by checking bitmap id
    if (bitmapFileHeader.type !=0x4D42) {
        LOG_ERROR("Invalid file '%s'", filename);
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Read the bitmap info header
    fread(bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader), 1, filePtr);

    // Move file point to the beginning of bitmap data
    int failed = fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.offBits, SEEK_SET);

    if(failed != 0) {
        LOG_ERROR("Seeking bitmap failed");
        free(bitmapImage);
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Read bitmap image data
    bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmapInfoHeader->sizeImage);

    if (!bitmapImage) {
        LOG_ERROR("Malloc failed");
        free(bitmapImage);
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    fread(bitmapImage, bitmapInfoHeader->sizeImage, 1, filePtr);

    // Make sure bitmap image data was read
    if (bitmapImage == NULL) {
        LOG_ERROR("Unable to read bitmap data");
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }

    fclose(filePtr);
    return bitmapImage;
}

int overwriteBitmapData(char* filename, unsigned char* data)
{
    FILE* filePtr;
    BitmapFileHeader bitmapFileHeader;
    BitmapInfoHeader bitmapInfoHeader;

    // Open filename in read write binary mode
    filePtr = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if (filePtr == NULL) {
        LOG_ERROR("Failed to open file: '%s'", filename);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Read the bitmap file header
    fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BitmapFileHeader), 1, filePtr);

    // Verify that this is a bmp file by checking bitmap id
    if (bitmapFileHeader.type !=0x4D42) {
        LOG_ERROR("Invalid file '%s'", filename);
        fclose(filePtr);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Read the bitmap info header
    fread(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader), 1, filePtr);

    // Move file point to the beginning of bitmap data
    int failed = fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.offBits, SEEK_SET);
    if(failed != 0) {
        LOG_ERROR("Seeking bitmap failed");
        fclose(filePtr);
        return NULL;
    }
    // Overwrite data
    fwrite((void*)data, bitmapInfoHeader.sizeImage, 1, filePtr); 

    fclose(filePtr);
    return TRUE;
}
```

### Output

This is the output I get when I run this program for three different files:

1. imgSmall.bmp - 56KB
2. img.bmp - 65MB
3. imgBig.bmp - 436MB

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Welcome to grayscale with cuda.
> [INFO] Turning C:\Users\Bhathiya\Desktop\imgSmall.bmp to grayscale...
> [INFO] size=57456, dataSize=57456, pixelCount=19152
> [INFO] Image Width=167 Height=114
> [INFO] CUDA kernel launch with 6x4 blocks of 32x32 threads. Total threads=24576
> [INFO] Time taken: 0.027808 ms
> [INFO] Effective Bandwidth: 4.132336 GB/s
> --------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Welcome to grayscale with cuda.
> [INFO] Turning C:\Users\Bhathiya\Desktop\img.bmp to grayscale...
> [INFO] size=68623200, dataSize=68623200, pixelCount=22874400
> [INFO] Image Width=5400 Height=4236
> [INFO] CUDA kernel launch with 169x133 blocks of 32x32 threads. Total threads=23016448
> [INFO] Time taken: 21.931168 ms
> [INFO] Effective Bandwidth: 6.258052 GB/s
> --------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Welcome to grayscale with cuda.
> [INFO] Turning C:\Users\Bhathiya\Desktop\imgBig.bmp to grayscale...
> [INFO] size=457488000, dataSize=457488000, pixelCount=152496000
> [INFO] Image Width=18000 Height=8472
> [INFO] CUDA kernel launch with 563x265 blocks of 32x32 threads. Total threads=152775680
> [INFO] Time taken: 143.047546 ms
> [INFO] Effective Bandwidth: 6.396307 GB/s
> ```

Comment: Download this at : https://github.com/JaDogg/CudaGrayScale

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Just to be really picky: the output should have "CUDA" and not "cuda" since it's an acronym.
- Also minor: `printHelp()`'s argument can be a `const char*` instead.
- [You shouldn't cast the return type of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1950231).  This is already done for you.
- I know that macros are common in C, but they still don't have to be overused.

  Here's an example:

  > ```
  > #define xIndex (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x)
  > #define yIndex (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y)
  > ```

  These computations are already very common in CUDA, especially since they're used in place of raw loops.  Although they may be a bit long, there's still no harm in typing them all out wherever needed.  Plus, if there's any chance for the reader to misunderstand (or forget) exactly what `xIndex` and `yIndex` refer to, it could cause problems.

  Here's another example:

  > ```
  > #ifndef EXIT_SUCCESS
  > #define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
  > #endif
  >
  > #ifndef EXIT_FAILURE
  > #define EXIT_FAILURE 1
  > #endif EXIT_FAILURE
  >
  > #ifndef TRUE
  > #define TRUE 1
  > #endif
  >
  > #ifndef FALSE
  > #define FALSE 0
  > #endif
  > ```

  I don't think there's a chance of them being entirely undefined in a bare CUDA implementation, so you should still be able to use the respective libraries: `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdbool.h>`.

  There are other examples of this, but I won't mention them all.  Just consider other options, or just omit them, wherever possible.

Answer (score 6):

I also thought how I could improve my code further.

## Readability

First Convert, this

```
#define xIndex (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x)
#define yIndex (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y)
    unsigned long dataIndex = (xIndex + (yIndex * width)) * PIXEL_SIZE;
#define BLUE bitmapData[dataIndex]
#define GREEN bitmapData[dataIndex+1]
#define RED bitmapData[dataIndex+2]
```

to

```
#define xIndex (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x)
#define yIndex (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y)
#define BLUE bitmapData[dataIndex]
#define GREEN bitmapData[dataIndex+1]
#define RED bitmapData[dataIndex+2]
    unsigned long dataIndex = (xIndex + (yIndex * width)) * PIXEL_SIZE;
```

Also, this section needs more comments, and I should avoid magic numbers

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(32, 32);
dim3 blocksPerGrid((header->width + threadsPerBlock.x - 1) / threadsPerBlock.x,
    (header->height + threadsPerBlock.y - 1) / threadsPerBlock.y);
```

Becomes,

```
// Calculate number of threadsPerBlock and blocksPerGrid
dim3 threadsPerBlock(THREAD_PER_2D_BLOCK, THREAD_PER_2D_BLOCK);
// Need to consider integer devision, and It's lack of precision
// This way total number of threads are newer lower than pixelCount
dim3 blocksPerGrid((header->width + threadsPerBlock.x - 1) / threadsPerBlock.x,
    (header->height + threadsPerBlock.y - 1) / threadsPerBlock.y);
```

Also this is not formatted correctly

```
CUDA_LOG_TIME(size*2.0f/milliseconds/1e6f);
```

Becomes,

```
// Log Effective Bandwidth and total time
// It is necessary to multiply by 2 because both read and write operations
// Occur
CUDA_LOG_TIME(size * 2.0f / milliseconds / 1e6f);
```

## Performance

Things to remember:

1. `blockDim` contains `32` for both `x` and `y` since that is what we are using for `threadsPerBlock`.
2. Bitwise calculations (shifting `<<`, `>>`) are faster than `/` and `*`
3. Instead of multiplying by `32` why not shift left `5` times. (`2^5 = 32`)
4. Average of `3` elements can be calculated using averages of `2` elements twice. Also instead of dividing by `2` to calculate average using this method, one can use shift right by `1` time. (`2^1 = 2`)

Finally

```
#define PIXEL_SIZE 3
// My GPU Has 1024 Threads per block, thus 32x32 threads
// 32 = 2^5, therefore 32 is 5 bits
#define THREAD_PER_2D_BLOCK 32
#define THREAD_PER_2D_BLOCK_BITS 5

// Turn given bitmap data to gray scale
__global__ void turnGray(unsigned char* bitmapData, unsigned long size, unsigned int width)
{
    // This is done because shifting left by 5 is faster than multiplying by 32
    // Since the 5 least significant bits are zeros after shifting it is possible to use
    // Much faster `bitwise or` to calculate addition. (Since no need to carry the one)
    // The reason it becomes feasible is because threadId is between 0..31
#define xIndex ((blockIdx.x << THREAD_PER_2D_BLOCK_BITS) | threadIdx.x)
#define yIndex ((blockIdx.y << THREAD_PER_2D_BLOCK_BITS) | threadIdx.y)
#define BLUE bitmapData[dataIndex]
#define GREEN bitmapData[dataIndex+1]
#define RED bitmapData[dataIndex+2]
    unsigned long dataIndex = (xIndex + (yIndex * width)) * PIXEL_SIZE;
    // Gray occurs when RED == GREEN == BLUE, so get average
    if(dataIndex < size) {
        // This is done because shifting right is faster than division
        // And average can be calculated in two steps
        unsigned char gray = (((RED + GREEN) >> 1) + BLUE) >> 1;
        // Convert all pixels to gray
        RED = gray;
        GREEN = gray;
        BLUE = gray;
    }
#undef RED
#undef GREEN
#undef BLUE
#undef yIndex
#undef xIndex
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Welcome to grayscale with CUDA.
[INFO] Turning C:\Users\Bhathiya\Desktop\imgSmall.bmp to grayscale...
[INFO] size=57456, dataSize=57456, pixelCount=19152
[INFO] Image Width=167 Height=114
[INFO] CUDA kernel launch with 6x4 blocks of 32x32 threads. Total threads=24576
[INFO] Time taken: 0.025888 ms
[INFO] Effective Bandwidth: 4.438814 GB/s
--------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Welcome to grayscale with CUDA.
[INFO] Turning C:\Users\Bhathiya\Desktop\img.bmp to grayscale...
[INFO] size=68623200, dataSize=68623200, pixelCount=22874400
[INFO] Image Width=5400 Height=4236
[INFO] CUDA kernel launch with 169x133 blocks of 32x32 threads. Total threads=23016448
[INFO] Time taken: 20.712543 ms
[INFO] Effective Bandwidth: 6.626245 GB/s
--------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Welcome to grayscale with CUDA.
[INFO] Turning C:\Users\Bhathiya\Desktop\imgBig.bmp to grayscale...
[INFO] size=457488000, dataSize=457488000, pixelCount=152496000
[INFO] Image Width=18000 Height=8472
[INFO] CUDA kernel launch with 563x265 blocks of 32x32 threads. Total threads=152775680
[INFO] Time taken: 135.375641 ms
[INFO] Effective Bandwidth: 6.758793 GB/s
```

**Effective Bandwidth Increment:** 6.396307 GB/s →  6.758793 GB/s

Comment: The optimizing compiler may already do some of these performance things for you, but yeah, it's still good to be aware of them.

Comment: @Jamal Yes you are correct. However it shows a performance improvement. I'm using MSVC at the moment.